# Converting *.jpg scanned from line paper map to vector data in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, digitizing, jpg

I want to digitize automatically old paper map that scanned to jpg  .
I know that it's possible to digitize it with arc-map but I can not remember how to do it.

Comment: do you have access to arcscan ?

Comment: Is the file in RGB format?  If so I think you won't be able to use Arcscan as suggested without converting it to binary or classified.  You might see if it can be rescanned to binary before georeferencing it.  A program called Matlab (I've never used it) can do conversion based on searches.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds you are after automatic raster to vector conversion and the extension to ArcGIS for Desktop that does that (as mentioned in a comment by @radouxju) is [ArcScan](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000w00000001000000):

> ArcScan provides tools that allow you to convert scanned images into
>   vector-based feature layers. The process of converting raster data to
>   vector features is known as vectorization. Vectorization can be
>   performed manually by interactively tracing raster cells or
>   automatically using the automatic mode.

I've lost track of how licensing for ArcScan works but this [GeoNet thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/47678) answered by an Esri staff member suggests that that at ArcGIS 10.1 it became included with all license levels.

Answer (score 1):

1. Scan the map to xxx format and add the map to ArcGIS (sounds like you have it in jpg already).
2. Use the [Georeferecning Tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t000000mp000000) to get the map in the correct location using ancillary data. A good time to set the projection.
3. Create empty point, line, and polygon [Feature Classes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002p000000).
4. Using the [Editing Toolbar](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m500000002000000) to digitize your features into the files
5. Add required [attributes](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/1002/files/table_2.pdf).